# How to call two action in one tag a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

My tag a link is like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'dashboard' ?>" class="check_session">Home</a>
```

When click link home, it will call dashboard. When call dashboard, I want to check session. If session exist, call dashboard. If session no exist, logout

My javascript code is like this :

```
$(".check_session").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"shared/check_session/"+Math.random()+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response){     
            if(response == 'out')
            {
                alert('Please login');
                window.location.href = base_url + "logout"; 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem :

When link home clicked, it no call check session function

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't use the PHP $_SESSION global ? I don't get how you store your sessions. With `if(isset($_SESSION))` --> if true, include dashboard, else include login page... You can do it all server side on load of any ressource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior of anchor:

```
$(".check_session").click(function(e) { // <-----get the event here
    e.preventDefault(); //<--------here stop the default behavior
    var url = this.href; // <---get the url
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"shared/check_session/"+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response){     
            if(response == 'out'){
                alert('Please login');
                window.location.href = base_url + "logout"; 
            }else{
                window.location.href = url; // <----navigate to it here.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when you click this anchor it gets navigated to the specified `href` so your ajax never get called. In such case if you have bound any event on the anchors make sure you stop the default behavior with `event.preventDefault()`.

Although `Math.random()` is not needed `new Date().getTime()` would do this.

Comment: After run class check session, it not call action : `<a href="<?php echo base_url().'dashboard' ?>" `.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280802/how-to-change-amcharts-pie-themes

Answer (score 0):

If u wants to action better change a tag any div

and JS

```
$(".check_session").click(function() {
if(session = true)
{
 window.location.href = base_url + "dashboard"; 
}
else
{

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"shared/check_session/"+Math.random()+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response){     
            if(response == 'out')
            {
                alert('Please login');
                window.location.href = base_url + "logout"; 
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

and HTMl

```
<div class="check_session"> class="check_session">Home</a>
```

Comment: What is `session` ? And `session = true` ? I reckon this statement will always be evaluated as `true`

Answer (score 0):

Add `preventDefault()` at the first line in function and add a else condition to redirect to dashboard if session is true

```
   $(".check_session").click(function(e) {
      var targeturl = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"shared/check_session/"+Math.random()+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response){     
            if(response == 'out')
            {
                alert('Please login');
                window.location.href = base_url + "logout"; 
            }else{
                  window.location.href = targeturl; 
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want like this : `<a href="<?php echo base_url().'dashboard' ?>" class="check_session">Home</a>`. Because it's dinamyc href. So in javascript only `if`, no `else`

Comment: See Updated answer